# how to install or where to find a 2.6 mongodb cartridge for openshift

Tags: mongodb, openshift

Does anyone know how to install or where to find a 2.6 mongodb cartridge for openshift? I am assuming once found I can import it like any other externally maintained cartridge.

For example Redis: https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart

Comment: This question really deserves an answer. I've spent a good time now searching for more details about this matter, but to no success.

Comment: I found a trello board adressing many openshift cartridges, the upgrade is in the list, but not adressed. It was added in april. Here's a direct link: https://trello.com/c/mQjfeMFC

Comment: I moved to docker containers and kubernetes after not making progress here :(

Comment: I need mongodb-2.6 to run on OpenShift as well because of the $$ROOT variable... Anyone has any luck or advice?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/article/20141110231929-50035345-run-new-versions-of-node-js-mongodb-on-openshift-paas

This guy provides a 2.6 cartridge.